# Wordpress / PHP - How to show a page description

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to template editing in wordpress and I'm trying to get a page description to show up on my site but it is not appearing. The URL I'm trying to get to display the description is here:

http://fourwallsla.com/category/the-neighborhood/east-side/

and I've attached the screenshot of the page description within wordpress. It appears to be using the archive template (why is it not using the page template?).

Here's some of the code for the archive template:

```
<div class="main">
<?php if (have_posts()) : $first = true; ?>
    <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
    <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
      <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
      <h1><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
      <h1><?php echo get_the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h1>
    <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
      <h1><?php echo get_the_time('F, Y'); ?></h1>
    <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
      <h1><?php echo get_the_time('Y'); ?></h1>
    <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
      <h1><?php _e( 'Author Archive', 'gray_white_black' ); ?></h1>
    <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
      <h1><?php _e( 'Blog Archives', 'gray_white_black' ); ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>

    <ul class="post-list">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Where, in the code above, the_post(), appropriately, refers to the content for the home listing within the category displayed on the page. But how do I get the_post() for the page itself, shown in the screenshot? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: IMHO, you do it wrong template: check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Yeah seemed that way to me too, but I didn't build the theme, and I'd like to avoid changing templates since everything else is the way my friend wants it on her site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using the archive.php template because you are retrieving all posts within the category - 'In The Neighborhood' & 'East Side'. If you want it to use the default page.php you would have to publish a page in Wordress. 
To print the description ("Test Description") or the content of the post, add `<?php the_content(); ?>` or `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`after:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: Thanks - I do have pages published though. That's where the "test description" has been added - so I'm still a little confused as to what to do. I've figured out a workaround, but it's hardcoded, so it's not ideal. I installed a plugin called "Improved Include Page" which allows you to output a page's content in any template using it's ID. So I wrote a switch statement saying switch ($catName) { case "east side": iinclude_page(17); break; I'd like to find a dynamic way to do this though.

Comment: If you have the page published, go to Wordpress and then click on View page. It's permalink will be different, it won't have /category in its name. /category is making Wordpress load archive.php

Comment: I just noticed in the screenshot above, you have "/category/" in the permalink. Edit it out and give it a shot. It should load page.php template then.

Comment: Ah, okay - if I do that, I can still display categories within the page template, correct?

Comment: Sure. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories
To list posts inside those categories, just specify the catid you want to query before your loop.